# Problem with sudo apt-get each time I log on

Tags: apt, dpkg, lock

So recently I've started to face a completely new problem whenever I'm using the terminal for installing or updating any program. It reads

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

So I searched the internet and found a possible solution which was to know that which of the processes has a lock on dpkg and killing that process and it seems to work but I've to do it each time I log on to my pc. There seem to be 2 processes. This is what I did when I had to install nodejs

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
unattende 1234 root    4uW  REG    8,6        0 1049800 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo kill -9 1234
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
aptd    2787 root    8uW  REG    8,6        0 1049800 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo kill -9 2787
```

So I am wondering if someone can provide me with a permanent fix for this problem as this is getting too annoying.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the whole thing]

Comment: Presumably the `unattended-upgrades` service is re-spawning because it hasn't completed whatever it was doing; it *may* just be a matter of giving it enough time to complete - however if it's hanging for some reason you may find that examination of the log file `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` (and its gzipped rotated files if necessary) shed some light on the underlying issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the auto-update functionality of Ubuntu. Try waiting a few minutes after logging in and it should now run correctly.

To prevent this from happening at all, uninstall the `unattended-upgrades` package (which is kicking off those updates) with the following command:
`sudo apt purge unattended-upgrades`

After a reboot the problem you are facing should be gone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed all the updates manually and now the problem is gone :)